# Bind DependencyProperty in style

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, binding

I'm sure this is a simple thing to do, and to look up, but I've yet to have any luck.  Basically I want to style a WPF Slider such that when used I can give it two additional strings to display.

The new control looks like this:

```
public class SliderPicker : Slider
{
    public string LeftLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LeftLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LeftLabel", typeof(string), typeof(SliderPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    public string RightLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RightLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RightLabel", typeof(string), typeof(SliderPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
}
```

The style like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="SlickSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    ...
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding LeftLabel}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding RightLabel}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And usage:

```
<controls:SliderPicker LeftLabel="RealPreference" RightLabel="RealCoverage" Width="400" Style="{StaticResource SlickSlider}"/>
```

This doesn't seem to work.  So, how do I set the DP on the control and show it in the template?  I thought that's what TemplateBinding was for?

Comment: your markup seems right. Try to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the running application and check what the values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a small fix. Change `{x:Type Slider}` to `{x:Type controls:SliderPicker}`

You need to apply the custom control as the type in your style and template. Without it your trying to look for `LeftLabelProperty` and `RightLabelProperty` in `Slider` and not `SliderPicker` with your template binding.

Change your style to

```
<Style x:Key="SlickSlider" TargetType="{x:Type controls:SliderPicker}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:SliderPicker}">
                    ...
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding LeftLabel}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding RightLabel}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Have tried this with the class you've posted and it works fine :)

Comment: I actually just figure this out on my own.  And it fixed it!  Thanks.